# Journey Builder not progressing further

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have situation where my contacts in journey builder not progressing further i:e I can see population increased at wait (1 minute) then after many minutes it stays at same point. Next step is email and it is simple valid email.

[image]

Can some body provide a link for step by step journey builder which have details about contact builder as well.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the Send Email Activity is failing to send the email. There are a couple of things I would try:

### Channel Address Order

Ensure that one of the following has been configured:

1. The Email Address from your Event Source Data Extension is added as a Channel Address Order in Contact Builder (from the Contacts Configuration page) or,
2. In the Settings page for the Journey, select `EMAIL ADDRESS FIELDS FROM ENTRY SOURCE` as the Primary Email address.

### Triggered Send

A Send Email Activity is a Triggered Send. Open the Triggered Send from Tracking > Sends > Journey Builder Sends in the Email app and locate your Journey Version to see if the email is erroring. If it is, try previewing the email using the Send Preview feature (in the Email app) with your Event Source DE.

Comment: after reading this https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000220316
I think my contact builder/data design is wrong.

Comment: That help article specifically refers to Contacts not entering a journey, but clearly yours are. The problem appears to be related to sending the email.

Comment: Eliot you are absolutely right. I was hoping you see my problem and I was lucky :).

I tell you my situation .
If I add contact using REST API email works and contact added to journey builder.
Problem comes when triggered using Automation Fire Event.
Contact not adding to Journey builder. 
I followed your instructions yesterday and it did added to journey builder once then it halts at wait.

To me we need to revisit our data design (contact builder) and then go through our emails. We are using de attributes in our email  and ampscript to add record back to salesforce object .

Comment: I'd start off by trying to preview the email using the Send Preview feature (in the Email app) with your Event Source DE.

Comment: Again you are right, if I go for send preview it returns invalid recipient, if I do validate it returns no error. :(

Comment: We've seen this behavior before. Oddly enough, it was related to the cardinal relationships being incorrect in the Contact Model. Why this has anything to do with previewing an email, I'm not sure.